# addClass Before Ajax Load

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am attempting to add a class to an element contained within an Ajax-loaded page prior to it being displayed in the browser in jQuery. Here is my code:

```
$("#landing li.nav4 a").live('click', function() {
    $("#landing").fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#agency').load('assets/ajax/agency.html').fadeIn(function(){
            $("#agency-main nav li.nav1 a").addClass("nav1-on");
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

What happens at the moment is the page is loaded, and then the class is added and there is a noticeable "flash" as the class (background image) is loaded.

Any ideas how to load the content, add the class, and then fadeIn, in that order?

Comment: It's not clear when `"#agency-main nav li.nav1 a"` (a heavily over-qualified selector, by the way!) is available to the document in order to have its class added. Is this something that's always available, or only available inside of `agency.html`?

Comment: only available inside of agency.html

Comment: So `#agency-main nav li.nav1 a` is only available *after* `agency.html` has been loaded but you want to `addClass('nav1-on')` to it *before* `agency.html` is loaded into `#agency`?

Comment: Yes. And if that is not possible, some for of smoke and mirrors, perhaps? Delay the fadeIn just long enough to add the class before visible to the browser?

Comment: You could do it with `$.ajax`. Load the HTML, add the class, and then insert it in the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a jquery noob so this is more for my own learning - why not this?

```
//make sure #agency is defaulted to display:none, or add a line to check this
$("#landing li.nav4 a").live('click', function() {
  $('#agency').load('assets/ajax/agency.html', function() {
    $("#agency-main nav li.nav1 a").addClass("nav1-on"); 
  });
  $("#landing").fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('#agency').fadeIn();
   });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: `"#agency-main nav li.nav1 a"` is inside agency.html, therefor agency.html has to load first before the class can be added to it.

Comment: the only real downside is if agency.html takes a long time to load they could be wondering why nothing happens after they click. Could load a loading.gif...

Comment: swap out the .live() (deprecated) and the return false. Cache the created `$('#agency')` object. Then you'll get... almost the same thing I already posted. ;-) I do like the order of events better in this one, though.

Comment: I thought that same thing Greg - that we posted the same thing albeit in a slightly different order and with the other 2 differences :) Oh and yours had more line breaks :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to create the element to which you want to associate the class in the background and then insert it when you want.

like..

```
el = $("#landing");
//fadeout el
//remove from html
//add class
//insert it back in
```

if you can write the code on jsfiddle, thta would be very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Call me a nutbar, but I hate deciphering a million callbacks when all you need is a managed order of events:

```
$("#landing li.nav4 a").on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // better than return false;
  $agency = $('#agency'); // cache it since we use it twice

  // fade out the landing div, and when that's done load agency.html into #agency
  // presumably, #agency is already hidden
  $("#landing").fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $agency.load('assets/ajax/agency.html');
  });

  // add the class to the nav item
  $("#agency-main nav li.nav1 a").addClass("nav1-on");

  // fade #agency in
  $agency.fadeIn();
});
```

Notice 2 other recommended improvements that you can take or leave:

1. swapped out .live() for .on() which is available as of jQuery 1.7. If you're using older jQuery, you should still look into .delegate() instead of .live()
2. used preventDefault() to stop the click event from bubbling up to its default; this is more efficient and is easier to understand when reviewing the code.

Comment: Also: is there any possibility this is over-engineered, period? The jQuery isn't modular (it's a click specifically on `nav4 a` which ultimately modifies specifically `nav1 a`. This may be the intended result but it's not reusable!). So since it's so specific, why not just return agency.html with the class already added?

Comment: Yea, perhaps you're right. I was trying to avoid managing a bunch of removeClass'es from the tabs but I'd have to do that anyway. Thanks, all.